# How one can pass parameters to MSSQL query?

Tags: sql-server

I am doing a MSSQL function that takes computes Cronbach's alpha from given set of data. Here is my code at the moment:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS alpha;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE alpha
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'library(psych);
    a = tryCatch(alpha(Test), warning = function(w) {alpha(Test,check.keys=TRUE)})
    str(a)'
    , @input_data_1 = N'SELECT 
    CAST([ky1] as float) as ky1, 
    CAST([ky2] as float) as ky2,    
    CAST([ky3] as float) as ky3,    
    CAST([ky4] as float) as ky4,    
    CAST([ky5] as float) as ky5,    
    CAST([ky6] as float) as ky6,    
    CAST([ky7] as float) as ky7,    
    CAST([ky8] as float) as ky8,    
    CAST([ky9] as float) as ky9,    
    CAST([ky10] as float) as ky10,  
    CAST([ky11] as float) as ky11,  
    CAST([ky12] as float) as ky12,  
    CAST([ky13] as float) as ky13,  
    CAST([ky14] as float) as ky14,  
    CAST([ky15] as float) as ky15,  
    CAST([ky16] as float) as ky16,  
    CAST([ky17] as float) as ky17,  
    CAST([ky18] as float) as ky18,  
    CAST([ky19] as float) as ky19,  
    CAST([ky20] as float) as ky20 
    FROM Vuodet'
    , @input_data_1_name = N'Test'
END;
GO
EXEC alpha;
```

How can I change the code that a user can compute the alpha from the fields he or she wants rather than from the given fields ky1 to ky20?

Comment: I think this might be helpful [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/)

Comment: @Hatik I think it helps a bit but I think I need some dynamic structure to the parameters as the number of parameters can be an arbitrary positive integer.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic structure?

Comment: Where the number of parameters is not fixed.

Comment: "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS alpha;" is not MS SQL Server syntax

Comment: @sepupic Since 2016 it is correct.

Comment: @Rokuto, thank you, I did not know it; found it right now in CREATE PROCE article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add

```
@input_data_1 = @input
```

to the script.